# Shrink and grow an element using CSS3

Tags: css

I am trying to implement a grow and shrink effect on DIV element, this is working but the animation is working from left to right. Would like to make it from center.

Below I have placed the code, and here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2BGb/2/)

```
    .elem {
        position:absolute;
        top : 50px;
        background-color:yellow;
        left:50px;
        height:30px;
        width:30px;
        -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
        -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
        -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-name: grow;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -moz-animation-name: grow;
        -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes grow {
        from {
            height:30px;
            width:30px
        }
        to {
            height:130px;
            width:130px
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes grow {
        from {
    height:30px;
    width:30px
}
to {
    height:130px;
    width:130px
}
    }
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `transform: scale(n)` instead of changing the width/height

```
@keyframes grow {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(4.333);
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2BGb/5/)

You shouldn't need the browser prefixed versions at this point in time.

Keep in mind that scaling an element like an image to 4.3x its full size will make it blurry, so it might be better to make the default (1 / 4.3)x to start, then scale it up to 1 in the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to shrink back with animation once growing is completed?

Comment: @redV Sure, use `animation-direction:alternate`, prefixed of course

Comment: Note that these days prefixes are not needed. Also it's usually best to start at a scale below 1 and go up to 1 instead of going to a scale above 1